# Error registering parachain using zombienet

Tags: parachain, zombienet

Getting this message in the log

```
2023-08-12 02:58:12 [Parachain] Could not find the header of the genesis block in the database! block_hash=0x68d4f093429e67003e9b212826f3b2a0aeba6b6a84755aa006c1bd67bcef8758
```

The relay chain produces blocks but when registering the parachain and including genesis-wasm & state, the parachain registers but the logs give out that error.

Tinkering with I dont know if thats the issue in wasm file or genesis-state file, but all files are fresh.

.toml file:

```
    [settings]
bootnode = false

[relaychain]
chain = "polkadot"
default_command = "../bin/polkadot"
chain_spec_path = "../../polkadot/tmp01/rococo-local.json"
bootnode = false

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000
addToGenesis = true
cumulus_based = true
chain_spec_path = "tmp1/vane.json"
bootnode = false

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "vane-collator1"
  command = "./target/release/vane-node"
  genesis_wasm_path = "tmp1/vane-wasm"
  genesis_state_path = "tmp1/vane-state"
```

Version: latest

Comment: Hi @mrisho-lukamba, can you include more info like the config (toml) and versions that you are using? Thx!

Comment: Hi @mrisho-lukamba, thanks for updating the question. Does the relaychain chain-spec is in plain or raw format? Did you try remove the `paths` and let zombienet create all the artifacts?

Comment: Hi @pepoviola, nop I included the paths and also when I just run relay chain nodes and run collator node manually it works fine, Also wanted to register the parachain directly using zombienet.

Comment: Thanks @mrisho-lukamba, I also notice that you set `chain = "polkadot"` and the path of the relaychain spec mention `rococo-local`. Can you change the config to use `chain = "rococo-local"`. Also, for trying to reproduce I will need to know the repo for compile the collator.

Comment: Hi @pepoviola https://github.com/2-5-Foundation/vane/blob/main/zombienet-config/vane.toml